# How to create a single object for a class in flask models

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In `models.py` I have the following class that I would like to create a single instance of it while the application is initializing so that when I view my database one item with the name `name` is in the database without me doing anything

```
class Item(db.Model , UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer , primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, default="name")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a simple query that runs on startup after `db.create_all()` that checks whether there are any rows
in the `items` table and adds one if there are none.

```
num_items = db.session.query(Item).count()

if not num_items:
    item = Item() # Add parameters for UserMixin columns values if needed
    db.session.add(item)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Is it secure to add this in the `app.py` file

Comment: @packetsniffer I don't see why not. No matter where you put this, this will only add an item if there are no items already in the `items` table.